# drupal #default_value not applied in select option in drupal_render

Tags: drupal-7, render, default-value, drupal-forms, drupal-render

I try to print a drupal 'select option' element in a form .I think `drupal_render` not applying `#default_value`.every thing is ok except `#default_value` not applied.
where is the problem?anybody know how i can do this?
do `#default_value` accept `string` value?

**this is pseudo of my codes:**

```
function test_menu(){
$items=array();

    $items['admin/config/regional/test']=array(
    'title' => 'test',
    'description' => t('test'),
    'page callback' =>'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('test_function'),

);
$items[]=array();
return $items;
}


function test_function(){
 $header = array
  (
  'test1' => t('test1'),
  'test2'=> t('test2'),
  );
 $a=(1,2,3);
 $$options=array();
 foreach($a as $i=>$v)
  {
    $f['type'] = array(
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#options' => array(1,2,3,4),
   '#default_value'=>1,
    );
$options += array($name=>array( 'test1' => $v,
   'test2'=> drupal_render($f['type']) ,
  }
   $form['table'] = array
   (
   '#type' => 'tableselect',
   '#header' => $header,
   '#options' => $options,
   '#multiple' => FALSE
   //'#empty' => t('No users found'),
   );
   $form['submit'] = array
       (
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
   return $form;
 }
```

I test  `textfield` but its also not work and not accept `#default_value` in drupal_render

```
    $f['test3']=array(
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=>'test3',
    '#default_value' =>'aaa',
);
```

I suppose this is beacuse using drupal_render .anybody have a solution?

Comment: One thing people should be aware of when working with this is that the autocomplete attribute should be set to 'off' or Firefox wont show the selected option as selected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Drupal_render 's used in drupal_get_form , #default_value not set use must use #value instaed of it.

```
$f['type'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('1','2','3','4')),
'#value'=> '1',
);
```

Comment: This is dangerous as user will not be able to override the submitted value (Description: Used to set values that cannot be edited by the user. Should NOT be confused with #default_value, which is for form inputs where users can override the default value.) https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#value

Comment: Thanks so much, this answer is correct and solved my stuck

Comment: @TrungLeNguyenNhat you're welcome, I happy to seen my answer could help another guys after some years :)

Answer (score 4):

The following code doesn`t work:

```
$form['title'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('opt1'), t('opt3'), t('opt4'), t('opt5'), t('opt6'))),
'#default_value' => array($default_value_key));


$form['title1'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('opt1'), t('opt3'), t('opt4'), t('opt5'), t('opt6'))),
'#default_value' => array($default_value_key));

return $form;
```

But then i did the following:

```
$form['group'] = array('#tree' => TRUE);

$form['group']['title'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('opt1'), t('opt3'), t('opt4'), t('opt5'), t('opt6'))),
'#default_value' => array($default_value_key));


$form['group']['title1'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('opt1'), t('opt3'), t('opt4'), t('opt5'), t('opt6'))),
'#default_value' => array($default_value_key));

return $form;
```

And default values now works.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. finally, i found one method. As you said, the default_value does not work. So make the default_value fixed as 0. and change the options array, put the default value on the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example from [Drupal's Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select), you'll see that the `#options` setting takes a key-value pair array and in the `#default_value`, you should specify the **key** of the default value, not the string value.

Also, according to [documentation for the `#options` setting](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#options), `#options` is expecting String values.  So your select should be more like:

```
$f['type'] = array(
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('1','2','3','4')),
   '#default_value'=> '1',
);
```

Comment: .It's not working with drupal_render. In my orgin code i set array keys . the problem is  'drupal_render' that use in drupal_get_form not set #default_value.